# Zoho Oauth flow returning invalid client

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, zoho, zohobooks

I am trying to build a Oauth flow using python Django. The goal is to get the access token for zoho and save it to DB. but at the step where we exchange access token by sending `authorization_code`, I am getting invalid-client error.  I couldn't figure out what's wrong.

I have tried changing to .in domain in token url but that too didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have registered your Django as a Zoho client at:
https://accounts.zoho.com/developerconsole

More generally, the Zoho's api-client setup documentation is currently (April 2023) at:
https://www.zoho.com/accounts/protocol/oauth-setup.html

Comment: I have followed each step exactly but still i am getting invalid client error. if client is invalid then why it's not giving error on consent screen.?

Comment: I agree, it would be helpful if there were more feedback when configuring a client at Zoho's developerconsole.